# Mysql select query grouping by wildcards

Tags: mysql, select, sum, wildcard

Having trouble grouping active forum sum results by wildcards.

Ultimately, I want all the results that have similar names grouped and summed in distinct rows.

table: forums

columns: game, posts

current query:

```
SELECT game, sum(posts) FROM forums WHERE posts>1 AND game like
'%rift%' OR game like '%swiftsure%' GROUP BY name
```

current results:

> Game  **posts**
>
> Rift (PVP Defiant): Briarcliff    **3406**
>
> Rift Guides   **100**
>
> Rift Leadership   **1541**
>
> Rift Raid Discussion  **1336**
>
> Rift Raid Leadership  **533**
>
> Rift: Cleric  **85**
>
> Rift: Mage    **87**
>
> Rift: Private **411**
>
> Rift: PVE Leadership  **113**
>
> Rift: Rogue   **56**
>
> Rift: Warrior **29**
>
> Star Wars The Old Republic PvP - Swiftsure    **7**
>
> SWTOR Swiftsure Leadership    **0**
>
> SWTOR: Swiftsure Private  **7**

Desired results would look like this:

> Game | **posts**
>
> Rift | **7697**
>
> Swiftsure | **14**

I certainly appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for generic groupings, I would do a CASE/WHEN as the column...

```
SELECT case when game like '%rift%'      then 'Rift   '
            when game like '%swiftsure%' then 'Swiftsure'
       end as GroupName,
       count(*) as  PostCount
   from
      forums
   where
         game like '%rift%' 
      OR game like '%swiftsure%' 
   GROUP BY
      GroupName
```

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN name LIKE  '%rift%'
THEN  'Rift   '
WHEN name LIKE  '%swiftsure%'
THEN  'Swiftsure'
END AS GroupName, SUM( posts ) AS PostCount
FROM ipb_forums
WHERE name LIKE  '%rift%'
OR name LIKE  '%swiftsure%'
GROUP BY GroupName
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: This code feels very brittle. There's duplication(rather triplication) of string. And this cannot count non-matching criteria. When there's a requirement to count non-matching rows, it's hard to fashion this query to that requirement. See my answer here, look for George: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10387677

Comment: For pulling varied reports from static data, you are correct in that yours is much cleaner and more efficient.  The query from DRapp works better for me because of the dynamic nature of our forums.  We are adding new forums all the time, and I'd rather add a couple lines to the query rather than rebuild a temporary table each time I want to run the report.  That said, I have archived data that will be using your version. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6be7/4

```
select x.Name, COUNT(p.Name)
from
(
  SELECT 'JOHN' AS NAME
  UNION
  SELECT 'PAUL'  
  ) as x
LEFT JOIN Person p ON p.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',x.NAME, '%')
GROUP BY x.Name
```

Sample data:

```
create table person
(
  name varchar(100)
  );


insert into person values
('JOHN LENNON'),
('WINSTON JOHN LENNON'),
('MICHAEL JOHN FOX'),
('PAUL McCartney'),
('SEAN PAUL DATA'),
('GREAT PAUL OF FIRE'),
('ST PAUL OF X');
```

Output:

```
NAME    COUNT(P.NAME)
JOHN    3
PAUL    4
```

---

If you want to count GEORGE, you just have to add it on UNION:

```
select x.Name, COUNT(p.Name)
from
(
  SELECT 'JOHN' AS NAME
  UNION
  SELECT 'PAUL'  
  UNION
  SELECT 'GEORGE'
  ) as x
LEFT JOIN Person p ON p.Name LIKE CONCAT('%',x.NAME, '%')
GROUP BY x.Name
```

Output:

```
NAME    COUNT(P.NAME)
GEORGE  0
JOHN    3
PAUL    4
```

---

Too bad MySQL don't have unnest function. Things are simpler with Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/87c74/5

```
select x.Name, count(p.Name)
from 
unnest(array['John','Paul','George']) as x(Name)
left join Person p ON p.Name ilike concat('%',x.Name, '%')
group by x.Name
```

You can even directly use the comma-separated string from your server-side language to Postgresql, just put a curly bracket around that comma-separated string: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/87c74/17

```
select x.Name, count(p.Name)
from 
unnest('{John,Paul,George}'::text[]) as x(Name)
left join Person p ON p.Name ilike concat('%',x.Name, '%')
group by x.Name
```

This works in Postgresql too, values list can be used directly in queries (whereas in MySQL, values list can be used only on DDL): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/87c74/9

```
select x.Name, count(p.Name)
from 
(values('John'),('Paul'),('George')) as x(Name)
left join Person p ON p.Name ilike concat('%',x.Name, '%')
group by x.Name
```

Values list on FROM clause works on Microsoft Sql Server too: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87c74/3

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with:

```
  INSERT INTO working_table (keyword, connection)
  VALUES ('rift', connection_id())('swiftsure', connection_id());

  SELECT w.keyword, count(*)
  FROM forums f
  INNER JOIN working_table w
  ON f.game LIKE CONCAT('%', w.keyword, '%')
  WHERE w.connection=connection_id()
  AND forms.posts>1
  GROUP BY w.keyword;

  DELETE FROM working_table
  WHERE connection=connection_id();
```

It'll run like a 2 legged dog though. Really, if I were doing this I'd use a proper search engine schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the two OR'd conditions in parentheses. AND has a higher precedence without them.

```
SELECT case when game like ... end as game, sum(posts)
FROM forums
WHERE posts > 1 AND (game like '%rift%' OR game like '%swiftsure%')
GROUP BY name
```